# sqoop job failing due to following reason

Tags: sqoop

java.lang.Exception: java.io.IOException: Mkdirs failed to create file:/user/City/_temporary/0/_temporary/attempt_local1259965155_0001_m_000000_0 (exists=false, cwd=file:/home/centos)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.runTasks(LocalJobRunner.java:489)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:549)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Mkdirs failed to create file:/user/City/_temporary/0/_temporary/attempt_local1259965155_0001_m_000000_0 (exists=false, cwd=file:/home/centos)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:447)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:433)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:926)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:907)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:804)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.RawKeyTextOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(RawKeyTextOutputFormat.java:98)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewDirectOutputCollector.(MapTask.java:653)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:773)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:270)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
18/12/05 13:14:05 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_local1259965155_0001 running in uber mode : false
18/12/05 13:14:05 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
18/12/05 13:14:05 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_local1259965155_0001 failed with state FAILED due to: NA
18/12/05 13:14:05 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 0
18/12/05 13:14:05 WARN mapreduce.Counters: Group FileSystemCounters is deprecated. Use org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.FileSystemCounter instead
18/12/05 13:14:05 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Transferred 0 bytes in 2.6049 seconds (0 bytes/sec)
18/12/05 13:14:05 WARN mapreduce.Counters: Group org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task$Counter is deprecated. Use org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskCounter instead
18/12/05 13:14:05 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Retrieved 0 records.
18/12/05 13:14:05 ERROR tool.ImportAllTablesTool: Error during import: Import job failed!

Comment: could you please add the running command of sqoop import?

Comment: I got the solution. I was running that command by a different user, than to HDFS user. That is why this error. Thank You fir your reply.